# Heartbeat/keep-alive service to refresh CSRF token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, frontend, csrf-protection

We have an Angular web application fully service oriented and the ng-front end is consuming the REST web services via ng-services (so far standard).
To avoid any automatic POST request from bots or programs we are using a CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) Token which is server validated and after 15 mins expires.

The problem: if we have long sessions on the same page without reloading, the token expires (for example during fairies or because of long forms).

The idea is to build a keep-alive service (heartbeat) to 'refresh' automatically in background the session (until the customer browser is open).

Any idea? best practice?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a keep-alive service on the backend to refresh the

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/api/keep-alive", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public boolean keepAlive() {
        //TODO refresh token session
        return true;
    }
```

In your main controller place:

```
 var v = setInterval(function () {
         currentlyFetching = $http.get('api/keep-alive');
  }, 15 * 1000);
```

And your keep-alive/heartbeat service is in place.